# Calling command with variable through batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that copies and moves stuff, but I am getting stuck dealing with Certificates. I have to use a command the vendor provides called `installrootcacert.cmd`, but I also need to pass the file name of the cert which is aptly named rootca.cer. I have to use the script the vendor provides so there is no way around that.

Normally I would run this from the command like like so:

```
c:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\installrootcacert.cmd rootca.cer
```

I have attempted to `call` the command from my batch file, but with no luck.

I tried to use a variable, but because that command calls several other processes, it is looking for "rootca.cer" after the command. If I place it in a variable, the other processes fail. I cannot modify the other processes.

```
echo @off
cd E:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\trustedCA
e:
call "e:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\installrootcacert.cmd rootCA.cer"
```

Comment: Quote only the path to the batch `call "e:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\installrootcacert.cmd" rootCA.cer`

Comment: Don't quote the whole thing..

Comment: `echo @off` will echo `@off` in cmd. Try `@echo off` instead.

Comment: As you're likely moving between drives too, please use the `/D` option with `CD`! Also as you've already changed to a known location and your script to call is relative to that location, you don't need to use its full path, you can use its relative one: `Call ..\installrootcacert rootCA.cer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. You need to adjust the `@` in your echo statement and your quotations:

```
@echo off
cd E:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\trustedCA
e:
call "e:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\installrootcacert.cmd" rootCA.cer
```

The reason that this works is because putting the command `@echo off` in your script stops ALL commands from being output. If you just have `echo @off`, you're literally going to echo that. (credit to double-beep for initially suggesting that)

As for the quotes, what you are trying to do is pass that as a command, so when you `call` the `rootCA.cer`, you need to make sure you are passing it the proper parameters, which is why you place that filepath in quotes. If you place the WHOLE object in quotes, you aren't actually issuing a `call` to the `rootCA.cer` command. (credit to LotPings for initially suggesting that).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Also, please **give credits** to your answers: you got that from the comment area.

Comment: Better? @double-beep. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Incorrectly phrased the second paragraph of explanations: that's not why you quote the file only.

Comment: Then please edit my answer or submit it for an edit. Or, alternatively, submit a better answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, might be:

```bat
@echo off
cd /d "E:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\trustedCA"
call "E:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\installrootcacert.cmd" rootCA.cer
```

- `echo @off` replaced with `@echo off` because `echo @off` will echo `@off` in cmd.
- It is mentioned by Compo in comments, you are changing drives: use `/d` option with `cd`.
- Finally, quote **only** the filename in the `call` command, else, windows will interpret this as a complete filename (i.e. `E:\vendor\Software\Conf\Security\installrootcacert.cmd rootCA.cer`, so filename will be `installrootcacert.cmd rootCA.cer`).